# Types with embedded references are not supported

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, content-management-system

I am getting this error while trying to run Squidex CMS project in vs 2017.
I have installed `Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.302

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0619  'ReadOnlySpan' is obsolete: 'Types with embedded references are not supported in this version of your compiler.'  Squidex.Domain.Apps.Core.Operations C:\Users\nithin.bc\Downloads\squidex-master\squidex-master\src\Squidex.Domain.Apps.Core.Operations\HandleRules\RuleEventFormatter.cs    82  Active

This is the code part where error exists

```
        var cp2 = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(ContentPlaceholderStartNew);
        var cp1 = new ReadOnlySpan<char>(ContentPlaceholderStartOld);
```

Comment: Which version of VS 2017 are you running? You will need at least VS 2017 15.5 (which ships with C# 7.2 capable compiler which is required for `Span<T>`, `ReadOnlySpan<T>` etc. because they require the new `ref struct` language feature)

Comment: @Tseng my version is 15.3.3

Comment: Upgrade your Visual Studio then, you won't be able to use the new language features. You can still target older versions of .NET Framework or .NET Core since its a pure language feature

Comment: Why the downvotes are for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Span<T>`, `ReadOnly<Span>` etc. were introduced just recently and use the new `ref struct` (see this [MSDN Blog: Welcome to C# 7.2 and Span](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/welcome-to-c-7-2-and-span/) and [CSharp Docs: Reference semantics with value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types)) language feature introduced in C# 7.2.

C# 7.2 requires a newer version of the complier which shipped with Visual Studio 2017.5 (15.5). You will have to install this (or a more recent) version of Visual Studio in order to compile projects which require C# 7.2 language features.

Comment: I get this error even with Visual Studio 2017 15.8.0

Comment: This is actually a ReSharper error that still pops up in Intellisense even though it works fine with the correct version of VS 2017.